# Inter process communication between Electron app and Win32 native desktop app

Tags: c++, electron, named-pipes, netmodules

I am trying to implement inter process communication between a desktop native app and an electron app on Windows for assignement(Operating systems).
I am new to this area and not able to find relevant links.
The options I have considered are:
1. TCP
2. HTTP server
3. COM
4. Namedpipes

NamedPipes seem correct, as electron implements its IPC using named pipes. There is a net module available which implements sockets that seem to be similar.
And I can write the server in the native app.

Does this sound correct to you guys? Any better alternatives? Any suggestions which will help me learn will be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the library node-ipc https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc which has a range of ways by which you can communicate between node (which is what basically electron is) and other system level processes.